# How to access selected tab tabcontrol from another component class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to access(get) the selected tab from tabcontrol from another component class. I want see what tab is pressed every time someone clicks on a different one.

I have a component class which is embedded into another class which has the tabcontrol in it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, add an event handler for the tab control's TabIndexChanged event in your other component class.

Answer (score 0):

Ex: you can use like this or you can achieve using property also

```
public class A
{       
    B obj1 = new B();
    private void tabControl1_TabIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        obj1.PageChanged(tabControl1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    }
}


public partial class B 
{       
    public void PageChanged(string Val)
    {
        //put your code 
        // after page chaged what should happen
    }
}
```